# Problems in conditional sum Crystal Report

Tags: crystal-reports

```
CurrencyVar Total; IF ({tblRecovery.Purpose}) = "Banana" THEN Total:= Total + {tblRecovery.Amount} else 0
```

I use this formula to show total amount of Banana but it shows every records of the data table. Which is not banana it's show 0 and which is banana it shows its value. And at the last row its show the total amount. I want to get total amount for banana in single text.

Comment: where are you write this formula i.e. any variable or else used.  Second thing, in which place you put this variable i.e. detail section or group section or header footer etc.

Comment: I write the formula in formula field named "XX" and i used the formula field in detail section.

Comment: Ok, so just move into footer means to put this field to page footer or group footer. Hint:- Whenever the summary field or calculate field we want, put into the footer and when we need the detail or say each row of data, put into detail section.